# Running multiple Maven profiles + Cucumber JVM

Tags: maven, cucumber

Since the Cucumber JVM does not support Profiles, I'm trying to use Maven instead.  What I want to do is activate a certain subset of tests based on its tag, and point it to the correct environment.

Here is my feature file:

```
Feature: Validate data

  @dev
  Scenario: Dev environment
    Given dev data

  @qa
  Scenario: Test environment
    Given test data
```

Here is my pom.xml:

```
...
    <profiles>
        <profile>
          <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <cucumber.options>
                    --tags @dev
                </cucumber.options>
                <base.url>http://dev.base.url.to.application</base.url>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
          <id>qa</id>
            <properties>
                <cucumber.options>
                    --tags @qa
                </cucumber.options>
                <base.url>http://qa.base.url.to.application</base.url>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>firefox</id>
        <properties>
            <driver.class>org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver</driver.class>
        </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>chrome</id>
                <properties>
                    <driver.class>org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver</driver.class>
                </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <systemPropertyVariables>
                                <cucumber.options>${cucumber.options}</cucumber.options>
                            </systemPropertyVariables>
                        </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

When I try to run multiple profiles at once, i.e., using the following command:

`mvn test -P dev,qa`

Only one of my tests gets executed.  If I run it without profiles, both tests get executed (the qa profile in specific).  Have I configured my profiles improperly?  Or is it an issue with my tags?

Comment: I am not sure you are providing the whole picture. Could you please rerun Maven with `help:all-profiles help:active-profiles test` with your different profile activations?

Comment: @Daniel I reran and received the following:

`The following profiles are active:

 - dev (source: hellocucumber:hellocucumber:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT)
 - qa (source: hellocucumber:hellocucumber:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT)
`

Comment: I'd guess that the tags from cucumber.options are not combined properly. Any way to find out which tags are run by Maven?

Answer (score 0):

In the `dev` profile you set the `cucumber.options` property to `--tags @dev`. In the `qa` profile you set the `cucumber.options` property to `--tags @qa`. So when combining these profiles with `-P dev,qa` the `qa` profile will override the value of the `cucucumber.options` set by the dev profile.

And because this is a single element [`combine.children=merge`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugins) will not work and there is no good way to merge these profiles.